# How to require/include ruby CSV library in rails 3.2 engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, csv

We would like to include ruby 2.0's CSV library in Rails 3.2 engine to export data in CSV. In rails app, the CSV library could be added to `application.rb` under `/config`:

```
require 'csv'
```

However there is no `application.rb` under engine's config. Where is the right place in rails engine for requiring ruby's library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's customary to put such `require` statements in `lib/my_engine.rb` or `lib/my_engine/engine.rb`, especially if you are using `CSV` in your engine.